# Jquery intermittently fails to hide rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently working on a facility booking system. In the process of booking a facility, users can choose a time slot. When the user picks a date and facility to book, an ajax call is made to retrieve all available time slots. The data returned includes the time slots for weekdays and weekends (yes, they have different time slots).

Weekday and weekend and time slots are placed in a table. There is another function to check whether that the chosen date is a weekday or weekend. If it is the former, the weekend time slots will be hidden. If it is the latter, vice versa.

**The opening time for weekdays: 08:00 - 21:00**

**The opening time for weekends: 08:30 - 17:30**

To hide said time slots, the following code is used:

```
if (lastId != end_time_id) {
    for (var i = lastId + 1; i <= end_time_id; i++) {
        $('#trTimeslot' + i).hide();   
    }
}
```

If the code works perfectly, the time slots will be shown like this:

**Chosen Date: 27 June 2017, Tuesday (Weekday)**

[image: Correct Time Slots]

**Chosen Date: 1 July 2017, Saturday (Weekend)**

[image: Correct Time Slots Weekend]

However, at times, the code does NOT work. At times, the time slots shown will show BOTH weekdays and weekends:

**Chosen Date: 27 June 2017, Tuesday (Weekday)**

[image: Wrong Time Slots Shown]

It must also be noted that 7 - 8 functions, filled with ajax requests, are called before the time slots are shown. The function to hide the "weekend" or "weekday" rows is the 5th function.

The question is, is there anything I can do to make sure the rows will be hidden before the time slots are shown to the user?

I do apologise that I cannot show more codes as the company is pretty sensitive on these kind of stuff.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cannot show more codes` - you haven't shown **any** code. Your chances of getting any useful answer is zero ... `the 5th function` I suggest you fix the fifth function

Comment: @JaromandaX I did show the jqeury code used to hide the table rows.

Comment: yes, you must've edited the question? and those 3 lines don't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to hide is running before the code that populates the time table, add the loop to the callback after the data is inserted to the time table and displayed.

Comment: This answer helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an absolute answer to the problem , I would rather suggest to do the opposite. From the problem description I assume there is an ajax call which return the data & following which the function triggers to hide the irrelevant rows. A minute delay will be there because of DOM traversal

Alternatively

1. Initially hide the view (weekends & timeslot).
2. Check for the condition and show only relevant data.
3. Till that time there can be a spinner in the screen to show work is in progress